# Question about the paper "Face spoofing detection from single images using texture and local shape analysis"

Tags: computer-vision

Could someone please explain to me how this block division was accomplished? I have tried really hard to understand but I have been unsuccessful. How is this image divided into 3x3 overlapping regions with an overlapping size of 14?

[image with block division](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zakxN.png)

[excerpt from the above paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lICMi.png)

[excerpt from another paper from the same author using the same division technique](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MrQIV.jpg)

I'd be very grateful if you could help me!

Thanks for your time.

Best regards,
Jefferson

Comment: How are we supposed to figure out what is going on from that image? Maybe you can copy-paste the relevant text from the paper that describes this division?

Comment: THAT'S THE PROBLEM! The paper doesn't describe the division! If it did I wouldn't be here asking for help. It just says that this is image has size 64x64 pixels and it is divided into 3x3 regions having overlapping size 14 pixels.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Now I've edited the post and added the "relevant" text from the paper you've asked for.

Comment: Maybe email the author and ask for clarification? I doubt anybody else would know. It makes no sense to me.